# Splitting a string using boost::split

Tags: c++, boost

I am fairly new to boost libraries and I am trying to split the following string using `boost::split`:

```
std::string line1 = R"(1500,"Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken",204400,350)";
```

I am trying to split the above string into:

```
{ "1500", "Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken", "204400", "350"}
```

I cannot use comma `,` as a delimiter for split, because the item inside quotes may contain commas. Is there way I can specify that ignore the delimiter inside quotes using any regexp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890895/using-escaped-list-separator-with-boost-split

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using escaped\_list\_separator with boost split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890895/using-escaped-list-separator-with-boost-split)

Comment: For education purpose an easy regex to split them: [a-zA-Z0-9."](?:[a-zA-Z0-9."\s]*),|\w\d+

Comment: Better one [^\s](?:[^,]*),?

Comment: it worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Using just standard library:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e62f336bfcba9048)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::istringstream line1(R"(1500,"Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken",204400,350)");

    char ch;
    struct { int id;
        std::string full_title;
        int64_t some;
        int64_t data;
    } record;

    if ( (line1 >> record.id) 
      && (line1 >> ch && ch == ',')
      && (line1 >> std::quoted(record.full_title))
      && (line1 >> ch && ch == ',')
      && (line1 >> record.some)
      && (line1 >> ch && ch == ',')
      && (line1 >> record.data))
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed: \n";
        std::cout << "  record.id = " << record.id << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.full_title = " << record.full_title << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.some = " << record.some << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.data = " << record.data << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 
  record.id = 1500
  record.full_title = Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken
  record.some = 204400
  record.data = 350
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Boost Spirit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70e49a54ce039ef3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

struct Record {
    int id;
    std::string full_title;
    int64_t some;
    int64_t data;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Record, id, full_title, some, data)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> quoted = '"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) >> '"';
    qi::rule<It, Record()> parser = qi::skip(',') [qi::int_ >> quoted >> qi::int_ >> qi::int_];

    std::string const line1(R"(1500,"Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken",204400,350)");

    Record record;
    if (parse(line1.begin(), line1.end(), parser, record))
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed: \n";
        std::cout << "  record.id = " << record.id << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.full_title = " << record.full_title << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.some = " << record.some << "\n";
        std::cout << "  record.data = " << record.data << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 
  record.id = 1500
  record.full_title = Rev, H., Tintin, K.H. Ken
  record.some = 204400
  record.data = 350
```